# ¿Como obtener la cantidad de registros posteriores en sentencia sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla donde guardo los comentarios de temas:

```
Id, id_tema, id_autor, comentario, fecha
```

Necesito hacer una consulta que me devuelva la cantidad de comentarios posteriores a un determinado comentario en el mismo tema. El dato que tengo es el Id del comentario, he probado esto pero no me devuelve resultados:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS num_comentarios
from sala_muro_comentarios
WHERE Id=36251
and Id > 36251
group by id_tema
```

¿Como podria hacer esa consulta?. Gracias!

Comment: Que intentaste????? esta consulta es bastante simple.. pero si no nos decis que intentaste, no podemos explicarte en que fallaste

Comment: Desde php lo mas simple seria recorrer el arreglo hasta encontrar dicho comentario, y de ahí seguir recorriendo aumentando un contador

Comment: No intente nada porque no se como se hace.

Comment: Es importante que intentes algo, que investigues y nos digas hasta donde llegaste.

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi ahi he agregado lo que voy intentando.

Comment: Genial!!! obviamente Id no puede ser igual a un numero y mayor a si mismo al mismo tiempo ;). de ahi podemos explicarte algo mejor.

Comment: Entiendo, pasa que yo necesito saber si hay comentarios posteriores en el mismo tema y solo cuento con el id del comentario en cuestion, se podra hacer?. Desde ya gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos porque falla lo que probaste:

```
WHERE Id=36251
and Id > 36251
```

Estas preguntando si cada registro tiene id=36251 y si ademas, al mismo tiempo, cada registro tiene id mayor a 36251. Obviamente, un registro tiene un id unico, por lo cual cumple una de las dos condiciones, pero no las dos al mismo tiempo. y como pusiste and, no va a funcionar, ya que and son las dos al mismo tiempo.

Ahora, suponiendo que podemos usar como base el id, o sea que a mayor id, el comentario es mas nuevo, tu consulta deberia ser algo asi:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS num_comentarios
from sala_muro_comentarios
WHERE id_tema=(select id_tema from sala_muro_comentarios where Id = 36251)
and Id > 36251
group by id_tema
```

Que hace esta consulta???? La parte de adentro:

```
select id_tema from sala_muro_comentarios where Id = 36251
```

Devuelve un solo registro, con el id_tema de ese comentario. Entonces, ese es nuestra tema, y el que usamos en la consulta principal. Y despues, lo verificamos solo para comentarios posteriores a este.

Answer (score 0):

Claro, pero con la segunda consulta puedes hacerlo:

**SELECT COUNT(*) AS registros_totales FROM tabla_comentarios WHERE (id_tema = XX) AND (id_comentario < YY);**

Esto te dará el numero (COUNT) de comentarios que hay despues del comentario (id_comentario) en cuestión de ese tema (id_tema)

Con un if de PHP lo tienes:

**if(registros_totales < 0){
 /* Aqui el boton de Borrar comentario */
}**

Esto lo que hace es que solo mostrara el boton de borrar comentarios siempre que no hayan mas comntarios despues del que tu necesitas saber de un tema en concreto ;)

Answer (score -3):

¿Que quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Un contador por ejemplo de comentarios de un tema? Depende de lo que necesites hay varias formas de hacerlo pero estaria bien saber el objetivo.

Si quieres saber cuantos comentarios hay, pues hacer un COUNT(*) de registros asociados a ese tema en concreto (ID del tema) restar 1 y ya lo tendrias.

**SELECT COUNT(*) AS registros_totales FROM tabla_comentarios WHERE (id_tema = XX);**

Esto te devolvería el total.(Donde XX es la ID del tema del cual cuelgan los comentarios)

Si quieres saber cuantos comentarios hay antes de uno concreto que digamos esta por ahí en medio, simplemente es con la ID de ese comentario hacer un tope:

**SELECT COUNT(*) AS registros_totales FROM tabla_comentarios WHERE (id_tema = XX) AND (id_comentario < YY);**

Donde YY es la ID del comentario en cuestión.

De todas maneras Patricio si nos das mas info de lo que quieres hacer concretamente te puedo dar una mejor solución

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo que quiero es saber si hay comentarios posteriores a un comentario en particular, en ese tema, de ser asi el usuario no pueda borrar su comentario. Lo que me falta es la consulta sql. Gracias!